# How to make override Django login

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-login

I want to override Django-login to make a custom login, but I can't find how.

The reason is that there's an specific situation where I cannot use `csrf` authentication, so I want to create a custom login, and afterwards, make a security layer that ensures my custom login is secure.

Any ideas?

Comment: just found a second after posting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: A Custom Login is not the same as a CSRF, and is not related at all. A custom login has to do with tokens, while CSRF has to do with a cookie.

Comment: Well, yes, I know that, the custom login is precisely to avoid using cookies (and CSRF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

The code was something like:

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
```

Comment: remember to wrap it in csrf_exempt so it will not show you the middle finger upon a POST request

Answer (score 6):

To overwrite the django custom admin, you have to create urls path and a view where you check and login/logout the user.
Take this for example:

urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'auth_view'),
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib import auth

def auth_view(request):

    # here you get the post request username and password
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')

    # authentication of the user, to check if it's active or None
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            # this is where the user login actually happens, before this the user
            # is not logged in.
            auth.login(request, user)

            ...
            return ...

    else :
        return HttpResponseRedirect("Invalid username or password")
```

Your html form:

```
<form role="form" action="/accounts/auth/" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 2):

In **urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'home/login.html'}, name='login')
```

In **login.html**

```
<form method="post">
{{ form.as_p }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<input type="submit">
</form>
```